# Isomorphism between Group Schemes over $\mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: modular-forms, group-schemes

Consider the Matrix

$$M:= \left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & d
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

for an odd $d \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Define the group scheme $Sp(g)$ defined over $\mathbb{Z}$ with symplectic form $g$ operating via

$g(x,y) = x^t\begin{pmatrix} 0 & M \\ -M & 0 \end{pmatrix}y$

My question is how to see that following isomorphism holds:

$$Sp(g) \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \cong Sp(4)\times \mathbb{Z}_2$$

here $\mathbb{Z}_2$ are the $2$ adic integers.

Where is the consition that $d$ is odd used?

Comment: Any odd number is a square in $\Bbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: @abx: this is only true for numbers congruent to $1 \pmod 4$.

Comment: Actually, $1\pmod 8$.

Comment: Oops, yes, I was too hasty, thanks.